# Online tanach with qamatz qatan marked?

Tags: tanach, grammar-dikduk, internet, product-recommendation

Although there are many places to find the Tanach online, I'd like to find one where qamatz qatan is specially marked. Preferably free, of course, though I'll take what I can get. Does anyone know of such a site?

Comment: Although I'm not the OP, it wouldn't hurt to also have one that distinguishes between shva na/ch and dageish qal/chazaq.

Comment: Scroll down here to verse 21: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/פרשת_בראשית/טעמים

Answer (score 2):

Not online, and not Tanach but a tikkun, which means Torah and maybe the haftara:
http://etzchayim.org/content/tikkun-comparison-chart

Since the website url changed at least once, I am including a screenshot of this chart as well.

[image: tikkun comparison chart]

Comment: That's a handy chart.

Comment: Once you're getting a book, might as well go with the tanach simanim:
http://www.zbermanbooks.com/Page.asp?ID=913866aaca735b055c48328a6c1074c7d146d2af85ba1e45c7fcf415dfe230e1&ProductID=145115

Comment: -1 because the OP asked for an online Tanach. Handy chart, though!